How to enable a Microsoft Teams bot to work in private channels?
We have developed a bot for Microsoft Teams that can send messages to:

Team members' personal chats
Public channels within the team

However, when we attempt to install the bot in a private channel, we encounter the following error:
"App isn't supported in the private channel. Select another channel."
We would like to enable our bot to:

Be installed in private channels.
Send messages in the private channel where it is installed.
Send messages to team members who are part of that private channel.

Is there a way to configure the bot or update its app manifest to support private channels? If so, what steps are required? Are there any limitations or additional permissions needed to achieve this?

The same issue is being tracked here https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/discussions/teamsdeveloper/how-to-enable-a-microsoft-teams-bot-to-work-in-private-channels/4352218. Please follow the above-mentioned thread for further updates.
